# Inserting from one table to another issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, primary-key

I'm having trouble trying to get the following stored procedure to work. I have a table of user groups that consists of a user_id and a group_id. Both ids are setup as primary keys and not null. What I'm trying to do is insert into this table all users that currently are in a group list into this table. To make it more clear I'm trying to do the following:

Users that are in groupIds 50, 52, 53 insert them into group 40.

Currently the stored procedure gives me a PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_user_groups'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ... The duplicate key value is (3, 40). When I look at the user_groups table I do see a record for 3, 40, but group 40 also contains users 5, 8, 10. I want users 5, 8, 10 to be added to group 40, but it fails due to user 3 already having a record.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
@targetGroupId int,
@groupList nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @list TABLE (groupId int);
    
INSERT INTO @list
SELECT * FROM SplitToInt(@grouplist, ',');

INSERT INTO user_groups(userId, groupId)
SELECT ug.userId, @groupId 
FROM user_groups ug 
INNER JOIN @list l ON ug.groupId = l.groupId
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT userId FROM users_groups WHERE groupId = l.groupId)
```

Comment: So you want to insert all users from 50, 52, 53 into 40, ignoring existing users in 40 and ignoring duplicates (say users in both 50 and 52)?

Comment: Developing lazy / bad habits. `INSERT INTO @list SELECT ...` Always specify a column list. Always schema-qualify object names. But there may be no need (or benefit) for a table variable either. Suggest reading [arrays and lists](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) in Erland's very useful website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two problems here:**

- You need to exclude all users *already* in group 40
- You also don't want to add users twice if they are in multiple other groups.

**We can solve the first problem with `EXCEPT` which will remove all existing users.**

`EXCEPT` also solves the second problem because it implies `DISINCT`

```sql
INSERT INTO user_groups(userId, groupId)
SELECT ug.userId, @groupId 
    FROM user_groups ug 
    INNER JOIN @list l ON ug.groupId = l.groupId
EXCEPT   -- EXCEPT implies DISTINCT
SELECT userId, groupId
    FROM users_groups;
```

---

Aside: you should use a proper table-type parameter instead of string-splitting:

```sql
CREATE TYPE GroupList AS TABLE (groupId int NOT NULL);
```

```sql
CREATE PROC yourProcedureHere
    @targetGroupId int,
    @groupList IntList
AS
.....
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for.